# Existence of nonconstant periodic solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Show that the given system has a nonconstant periodic solution:

$$\frac{dx}{dt}= 8x - 2y - 4x^3 - 2xy^2$$

$$\frac{dy}{dt}= x + 4y - 2y^3 -3x^2y$$

Above is my question. I tried to use the Poincare Bendixson Theorem. Consider the region that $\{(x,y): -2 \le x \le 2, -2 \le y \le 2\}$. Along the boundary, the vectors $(x', y')$ are pointing inwards. But I want a region where there is no equilibrium. In my region, there are 3 equilibriums, $(0,0), (1,1), (-1,-1)$. I can easily show that $(0,0)$ is unstable hence I can find a small closed curve enclosing $(0,0)$ and along the curve pointing away from the equilibrium. But what about $(1,1)$ and $(-1,-1)$? I cannot even prove that they are unstable. How to fix this problem? Thank you!

Comment: I did not modify your question. I only edited it: I chaged {\$...\$} to \$\{...\}\$ so the text look better. I don' ubderstand why this was considered to be a modification.

Answer (score 0):

Try a Lyapunov function $V(x,y)=\frac12x^2+y^2$,
$$
\dot V ·f = x\dot x+2y\dot y=8(x^2+y^2)-4(x^2+y^2)^2
$$
and contemplate the meaning of this function for the long-term behavior of the trajectories.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! But we need a region that contains no equilibrium. Using your method, whatever region we choose, (1,1) and (-1,-1) will always be in it. How should we deal with the equilibriums?